# Weighted + ordered tag search using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

After an AI file analysis across tens of thousands of audio files I end up with this kind of data structure in a Postgres DB:

```
id | name          | tag_1 | tag_2   | tag_3 | tag_4          | tag_5
1  | first song    | rock  | pop     | 80s   | female singer  | classic rock
2  | second song   | pop   | rock    | jazz  | electronic     | new wave
3  | third song    | rock  | funk    | rnb   | 80s            | rnb
```

Tag positions are really important: the more "to the left", the more prominent it is in the song. The number of tags is also finite (50 tags) and the AI always returns 5 of them for every song, no null values expected.

On the other hand, this is what I have to query:

```
{"rock" => 15, "pop" => 10, "soul" => 3}
```

The key is a Tag name and the value an arbitrary weight. Numbers of entries could be random from 1 to 50.
According to the example dataset, in this case it should return [1, 3, 2]

I'm also open for data restructuring if it could be easier to achieve using raw concatenated strings but... is it something doable using Postgres (tsvectors?) or do I really have to use something like Elasticsearch for this?

Comment: So is there a SQL query that you are using and is not working or what attempts have you made, is there some specific error you are getting?

Comment: Not at all :-/ The only thing that I know is that simple/regular queries (LIKE...) won't do the job. I'm currently playing around with ElasticSearch, but would prefer SQL ideally, except I have no idea about where I could start... any hint appreciated

Comment: Could you please give some details about key values according to the your example? Is this example depends on the data set you gave?

Comment: I get these keys / values from tracks in a playlists. The more a "tag" is used in the playlist, the more the weight (the value) grows. I actually posted a reply about my question, maybe  you could get a more accurate idea of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trials and errors this is what I ended up with, using only Postgres:

1. Turn all data set to integers, so it moves on to something like this (I also added columns to match the real data set more closely) :

```
id | bpm | tag_1 | tag_2 | tag_3 | tag_4 | tag_5
1  | 114 | 1     | 2     | 3     | 4     | 5
2  | 102 | 2     | 1     | 6     | 7     | 8
3  | 110 | 1     | 9     | 10    | 3     | 12
```

2. Store requests in an array as strings (note that I sanitized those requests before with some kind of "request builder"):

```
requests = [
  "bpm BETWEEN 110 AND 124 
   AND tag_1 = 1 
   AND tag_2 = 2
   AND tag_3 = 3
   AND tag_4 = 4
   AND tag_5 = 5",
  "bpm BETWEEN 110 AND 124 
   AND tag_1 = 1 
   AND tag_2 = 2
   AND tag_3 = 3
   AND tag_4 = 4
   AND tag_5 IN (1, 3, 5)",
  "bpm BETWEEN 110 AND 124 
   AND tag_1 = 1 
   AND tag_2 = 2
   AND tag_3 = 3
   AND tag_4 IN (1, 3, 5),
   AND tag_5 IN (1, 3, 5)",
   ....
]
```

3. Simply loop in the requests array, from the most precise to the most approximate one:

```
# Ruby / ActiveRecord example

track_ids = [] 
requests.each do |request|
  track_ids += Track.where([
                 "(#{request}) 
                 AND tracks.id NOT IN ?", track_ids
               ]).pluck(:id)

  break if track_ids.length > 200
end
```

... and done! All my songs are ordered by similarity, the closest match at the top, and the more to the bottom, the more approximate they get. Since everything is about integers, it's pretty fast (fast enough on a 100K rows dataset), and the output looks like pure magic. Bonus point: it is still easily tweakable and maintainable by the whole team.

I do understand that's rough, so **I'm open to any more efficient way to do the same thing**, even if something else is needed in the stack (ES ?), but so far: it's a simple solution that just works.